# Swap for Cake Margarine in the U.S.?

Tags: baking, substitutions

A *Great British Bake Off* question!

I'm interested in making a show-stopper cake ([recipe](https://thegreatbritishbakeoff.co.uk/recipes/all/karens-strawberry-fair-chocolate-cake/)) and it calls for "Cake Margarine" which is not available in the U.S. What is the equivalent that I can swap for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that "cake margarine" is regular margarine which has been whipped to incorporate air. As long as you're using a stand mixer to cream the margarine and sugar (and do so at high speed), I suspect regular margarine should be fine, as that creaming step is intended to accomplish the same thing. If you chill the mixer bowl in the fridge, it'll help avoid overheating the margarine during creaming, giving you more leeway for a longer beating time.

Comment: The recipe calls for creaming on step 2, so that's covered. There are some margarines that are not suitable for use under heated conditions, as the oils might degrade when exposed to higher temperatures (in the oven, not during the creaming), so what OP needs to check is if the margarine or shortening is suitable for baking

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substitute in kind, any margarine or vegetable shortening that is suitable for baking will do - it reads "Baking" on the label to indicate that the oils in the composition are heat resistant and will not degrade when exposed to oven temperatures.

[Example - Unsalted Baking Sticks @ Walmart.com](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Country-Crock-Unsalted-Baking-Sticks-Sunflower-Oil-Butter-16-Oz/279203923)